# OCR Tesseract for an app that can extract textual data from an image to be converted into a graph

Tags: java, android, extract, ocr, tesseract

The user will click dataF for first data while dataS for secondData then this button will crop the image selected from the previous class. The image needs to be crop for selecting the specific textual data I need and these data will be stored to a list to be used later on. I need a tesseract ocr to extract data. The data can be words or number because the data will be used in a graph so I also need to make the data stored seperatedly which is dataF and dataS respectively. I also want to make an error that if the user crop an image without words and numbers such as face then it will prompt an error.

```
package com.example.graphpick;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.util.Log;

public class Extract extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView nav;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private static final int DATA_F_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
    private static final int DATA_S_REQUEST_CODE = 4;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private List<String> extractedDataF = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> extractedDataS = new ArrayList<>();
    private TessBaseAPI tessBaseAPI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_extract);

        Log.d("Hello", "Hi");
        extractedDataF = new ArrayList<>();
        extractedDataS = new ArrayList<>();
        ImageView imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageButton arrowLeftButton = findViewById(R.id.arrowLeft);
        Button dataF = findViewById(R.id.dataf);
        Button dataS = findViewById(R.id.datas);
        ImageButton graph = findViewById(R.id.circleButton);
        TessBaseAPI tessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI();
        String datapath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Tess4J" +             File.separator + "tessdata";
        tessBaseAPI.init(datapath, "eng");


        String imageUriString = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri");
        if (imageUriString != null) {
            imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUriString);
            imageView1.setImageURI(imageUri);
            imageView1.bringToFront();
        }

        arrowLeftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent mainMenuIntent = new Intent(Extract.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(mainMenuIntent);
            }
        });

        dataF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startImageCrop(DATA_F_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        dataS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startImageCrop(DATA_S_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        graph.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (extractedDataF != null && !extractedDataF.isEmpty() &&
                        extractedDataS != null && !extractedDataS.isEmpty()) {
                    Intent mainMenuIntent = new Intent(Extract.this, Graph.class);
                    mainMenuIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("dataF", (ArrayList<String>) extractedDataF);
                    mainMenuIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("dataS", (ArrayList<String>) extractedDataS);
                    startActivity(mainMenuIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Extract.this, "Please extract data first.",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        nav = findViewById(R.id.nav);
        nav.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, true, true);
        nav.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, false, true);
        nav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.dummy);

        nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.Upload:
                        openGallery();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.Settings:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Instruction.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.About:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.Camera:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cam.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,     MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if (galleryIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

   private void startImageCrop(int requestCode) {
        Log.d("startImageCrop", "startImageCrop called");
        String imageUriString = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri");
        imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUriString);
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.OFF)
                .start(this);  // Start the image cropping process without a request code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult called");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == DATA_F_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Uri croppedImageUri = CropImage.getActivityResult(data).getUri();
                performOCRForCroppedImage(croppedImageUri, true);
            } else if (requestCode == DATA_S_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Uri croppedImageUri = CropImage.getActivityResult(data).getUri();
                performOCRForCroppedImage(croppedImageUri, false);
            }
        }
    }


    private void performOCRForCroppedImage(Uri croppedImageUri, boolean isDataF) {
        Log.d("performOCRForCroppedImage", "Executing performOCRForCroppedImage method");


        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(croppedImageUri);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // Convert Bitmap to a file
                File imageFile = convertBitmapToFile(bitmap);

                // Set the image file for OCR
                tessBaseAPI.setImage(imageFile);
                String extractedText = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text();
                tessBaseAPI.end();


                if (isDataF) {
                    extractedDataF.add(extractedText);
                    Log.d("ExtractedDataF", extractedText);
                } else {
                    extractedDataS.add(extractedText);
                    Log.d("ExtractedDataS", extractedText);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // Log the exception for debugging
        }
    }

    private File convertBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        Log.d("convertBitmapToFile", "Executing convertBitmapToFilemethod");
        File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
        File imageFile = new File(cacheDir, "image_for_ocr.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        return imageFile;
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) {
        Log.d("getBitmapFromUri", "Executing getBitmapFromUrimethod");
        try {
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I try this one to but the datapath of eng.traineddata is not exist even though I download it and put it inside the tess4j folder then tessdata and